# Writing value if found the key in a Key/Value reference table

Tags: excel, excel-formula

If I have a reference table like this:

```
Category |  ID
----------------
Cat1     |  12
Cat2     |  13
Cat3     |  14
```

And a csv file with the following cells:

```
Product Name |  Category   |  IDs   |    ...
---------------------------------------------
Pname1       |  Cat1       |        |    ...  
Pname2       |  Cat1 Cat2  |        |    ...  
Pname3       |  Cat1 Cat3  |        |    ...
```

The function applied to the Category coloumn need to lookup for key values (from Reference Tables) and, if found, write the ID value in the IDs coloumn, like this:

```
Product Name |  Category   |  IDs    |   ...
----------------------------------------------
Pname1       |  Cat1       |  12     |   ...  
Pname2       |  Cat1 Cat2  |  12,13  |   ...  
Pname3       |  Cat1 Cat3  |  12,14  |   ...
```

What's the best way to do that without nested IF conditions?

Comment: What is the MAX number of categories that any given record could have?

Comment: In theory there's no max value that a record could have. In case it's needed,can I calculate it counting the rows of the reference table in which I insert all the possible categories?

Comment: Yes, you can count it that way, but this now makes the problem extraordinarily difficult to solve with a formula. Your best bet is to use a VBA macro.

Comment: ▲ or a VBA User Defined Function (aka UDF)

Comment: To confirm: Your categories (Cat1 Cat2, etc) are delimited by a space but you want the IDs (12,14) delimited by a comma?

Comment: Yes exactly. The categories at the moment are delimited by a space but If needed I can do a simple find/replace and transform spaces into commas. The IDs instead must be separated by commas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tap <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd> and when the VBE opens, immediately use the pull-down menus to Insert ► Module (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>,<kbd>M</kbd>). Paste the following into the new code sheet titled something like Book1 - Module1 (Code).

```
Function collect_IDs(rCATs As Range, rREF As Range)
    Dim v As Long, vCATs As Variant, sIDs As String

    sIDs = vbNullString
    vCATs = Split(rCATs.Value2, Chr(32))
    For v = LBound(vCATs) To UBound(vCATs)
        If CBool(Application.CountIf(rREF.Columns(1), vCATs(v))) Then _
            sIDs = sIDs & Application.VLookup(CStr(vCATs(v)), rREF, 2, False) & Chr(44)
    Next v
    If Right(sIDs, 1) = Chr(44) Then _
        sIDs = Left(sIDs, Len(sIDs) - 1)

    collect_IDs = sIDs
End Function
```

Tap <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> to return to your worksheet. Use this User Defined Function (aka UDF) like any other native worksheet function. The syntax is:

> =collect_IDs(<cell with categories>, <lookup table>)

In your case this would be something like,

```
=collect_IDs(E2, $A$1:$B$4)
```

Your results should be similar to the following.

[image: Concatenate category lookups]

Comment: Thank you very much Jeeped for your solution. Do you know if there is the possibility to get it running on Open Office too?